# Rails and multi-databases, how would capistrano perform db updates on the db's?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

In a Saas environment, I want to have multiple databases for each customer (or group of customers, shared by some criteria).

When pushing updates using capistrano, how would all the databases be migrated?

If the db's get very large, is there a way to disable the db migration during capistrano runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd have to write your own custom migration tasks.

If you don't want migrations to run, don't have a database server with :primary => true set.